# Zend route xml with dashes and spaces

Tags: xml, zend-framework, routes

I have this problem. I have a route that looks like:

```
<Default_Taxonomy type="Zend_Controller_Router_Route">
    <route>taxonomy/:type/:tax</route>
    <reqs type="[a-z]+" />
    <reqs tax="[a-zA-Z\-0-9]+" />
    <reqs page="[0-9]+" />
    <defaults>
        <module>default</module>
        <controller>index</controller>
        <action>taxonomy</action>
    </defaults>
</Default_Taxonomy>
```

This is to route the taxonomy/category/hellocatname and it does. But what if i have a taxonomy/category/hello-catname or a taxonomy/category/hello catname ??

The  regex will not work with dashes ("-") or the  with spaces (" ").

How can i do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Browsers do not use spaces in urls so typically you do not need to check for them. Looking at your regex for `tax`, it *should* accept dashes. The regex for a space is `\s`

```
<reqs tax="[a-zA-Z\-0-9\s]+" />
```